# Creating a PHP/MySQL calendar unique to a user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, calendar

I have created a PHP/MySQL events calendar for a project that I'm currently working on, the calendar itself works as intended and the events are showing on the calendar also - however, I now want to make the calendar display events unique to the user profile. I am trying to pass the user id through the function call on the user profile page but I am struggling to get it to work and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant code from the user profile page is below:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include ('connections/conn.php');
include ('php/functions.php');
include ('functions_lean.php');

$id = htmlentities($_GET['profile_id']);

?>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="calendar_div">
      <?php 
              $userid = htmlspecialchars($_GET["profile_id"]);
              $mycal = getCalender(); 
              echo $mycal;
      ?>
          </div>
      </div>
```

The code for the actual function being called is as below:

```
      <?php
    /*
     * Function requested by Ajax
     */
    if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])){

            getCalender($_POST['year'],$_POST['month']);
    }

    /*
     * Get calendar full HTML
     */
    function getCalender($year = '',$month = '')
    {
            $dateYear = ($year != '')?$year:date("Y");
            $dateMonth = ($month != '')?$month:date("m");

            $date = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-01';
            $currentMonthFirstDay = date("N",strtotime($date));
            $totalDaysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$dateMonth,$dateYear);
            $totalDaysOfMonthDisplay = ($currentMonthFirstDay == 7)?($totalDaysOfMonth):($totalDaysOfMonth + $currentMonthFirstDay);
            $boxDisplay = ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay <= 35)?35:42;
    ?>


            <div id="calender_section">
                    <h2>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>');">&lt;&lt;</a>
                <select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>
                            <select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo getYearList($dateYear); ?></select>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>');">&gt;&gt;</a>
            </h2>
                    <div id="event_list" class="none"></div>
                    <div id="calender_section_top">
                            <ul>
                                    <li>Sun</li>
                                    <li>Mon</li>
                                    <li>Tue</li>
                                    <li>Wed</li>
                                    <li>Thu</li>
                                    <li>Fri</li>
                                    <li>Sat</li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="calender_section_bot">
                            <ul>
                            <?php 
                                    $dayCount = 1; 

                                    for($cb=1; $cb<=$boxDisplay; $cb++){
                                            if(($cb >= $currentMonthFirstDay+1 || $currentMonthFirstDay == 7) && $cb <= (
                                            $totalDaysOfMonthDisplay)){

                                                    //Current date
                                                    $currentDate = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-'.$dayCount;

                                                    include("connections/conn.php");
                                                    $getevents="SELECT * FROM miilearning_bookings WHERE date = '$currentDate'";

                                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $getevents);

                                                    // if there are rows of data it means that there is an event in the table

                                                    $eventNum = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                                                    if($eventNum > 0){
                                                    //there is a date with an event
                                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                                    $eventname = $row['studentid'];
                                                    $eventid = $row['id'];    
                                                    echo "<a href=event.php?id=$eventid>";

                                                    }
                                                    } else {
                                                    $eventname = " ";
                                                    }


                                                    //build each Date cell
                                                    echo "<li date='$currentDate' class='date_cell'><span>
                                                             $dayCount
                                                             <br> $eventname </span>
                                                                    </li>";

                                                    //condition to check eventNum 

                                                    if($eventNum > 0){
                                                        echo "</a>";

                                                    }

                                                    $dayCount++;

                                            }else{ 
                                    //display black cell
                                            echo "<li><span>&nbsp;</span></li>";

                                    } 
                            } 

                            ?>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                    function getCalendar(target_div,year,month){
                            $.ajax({
                                    type:'POST',
                                    url:'functions_lean.php',
                                    data:'func=getCalender&year='+year+'&month='+month,
                                    success:function(html){
                                            $('#'+target_div).html(html);
                                    }
                            });
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function(){

                            $('.month_dropdown').on('change',function(){
                                    getCalendar('calendar_div',$('.year_dropdown').val(),$('.month_dropdown').val());
                            });

                            $('.year_dropdown').on('change',function(){
                                    getCalendar('calendar_div',$('.year_dropdown').val(),$('.month_dropdown').val());
                            });

                    });
            </script>
    <?php
    }

    /*
     * Get months options list.
     */
    function getAllMonths($selected = ''){
            $options = '';
            for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
            {
                    $value = ($i < 10)?'0'.$i:$i;
                    $selectedOpt = ($value == $selected)?'selected':'';
                    $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i+1, 0, 0)).'</option>';
            }
            return $options;
    }

    /*
     * Get years options list.
     */
    function getYearList($selected = ''){
            $options = '';
            for($i=2017;$i<=2025;$i++)
            {
                    $selectedOpt = ($i == $selected)?'selected':'';
                    $options .= '<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selectedOpt.' >'.$i.'</option>';
            }
            return $options;
    }


    ?>
```

I have tried passing the $userid through the getCalender(); function as:

```
 getCalendar($userid);
```

then in the function page I changed

```
 function getCalender($year = '',$month = '')
```

to

```
 function getCalender($userid, $year = '', $month = '')
```

and finally I then altered my function query to

```
 $getevents="SELECT * FROM miilearning_bookings WHERE date = '$currentDate' 
 AND tutorid = '$userid'";
```

Ultimately, this works and the calendar does display events unique to each user but the issue arises when you use the calendar to move to a different month, or year. When you do this, the calendar goes to March 2017 and will not change dates thereafter.

Does anyone know why this may be?

Many thanks

Comment: See about prepared statements

Comment: Your getCalender function needs $year and $month as arguments.  Yet you defined your onClick events using strtotime, and provide only 1 argument.  I think this is where if fails, the getCalender functions does not receive both $year and $month like it requires.